# How to Call Parent Window JavaScript Function inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

Here is my code on `http://my-localhost.com/iframe-test.html`

```
<html>
<head><title>Welcome Iframe Test</title></head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.my-website.com/index.html" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertMyMessage(msg){
    alert(msg);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code on `http://www.my-website.com/index.html`

```
<html>
<head></title>Welcome to my Server</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to My Server</ht>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Click here" onClick="parent.alertMyMessage('Thanks for Helping me')">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When i Click the "Click Here" Link. i got following Error.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://www.my-website.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://my-localhost.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Please Help me to Fix this Issue, or give some other solution for this.

Comment: why are you using IFrames for this?

Comment: Then for this purpose what i can use? Actually my purpose is i have fixed html page which is going to open many websites. and those websites user have to click a link, and the link should call a function in the fixed html page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot access the DOM of a page loaded in a frame in a different origin. This is blocked for security reasons (imagine a random website you visited opening your web mail service in a hidden iframe and you can see why).

The closest you can come, and then only if you control both websites, is to pass messages between them using the [web messaging api](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/#dom-window-postmessage).

In one page, write a function to handle the messages and then add it as a message event listener.

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
  alert(event.data);
}

addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

In the other, send the message:

```
parent.postMessage("This is a message", "*");
```

See [MDN for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

Comment: Thanks will try :) and let you know

Comment: Thanks this method is working on Chrome. but in Safari its not working :(

Comment: @Quentin Neat. Using Chrome, I received the message, but it did not display the iframe window location. `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://stone.thecoreworlds.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Comment: @Chloe — That's because you have to use `postMessage` to pass the data, and the code that tries to read the location doesn't.

Answer (score 13):

You can use postMessage!

### PARENT

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener ("message", receive, false);        
}
else {
    if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage",receive, false);
    }
}

function receive(event){
    var data = event.data;
    if(typeof(window[data.func]) == "function"){
        window[data.func].call(null, data.params[0]);
    }
}

function alertMyMessage(msg){

    alert(msg);
}
```

### IFRAME

```
function send(){
    window.parent.window.postMessage(
        {'func':'alertMyMessage','params':['Thanks for Helping me']},
        'http://www.my-website.com'
    );
}
```

### REFERENCE

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: Use `##` for headers.

Comment: This works! But is there a way to dynamically populate 'http://www.my-website.com' instead of hard code?

Comment: I was able to use location.ancestorOrigins[0]) instead of hardcoded 'http://www.my-website.com'

Comment: I'm noticing that Window IE11 throws a SCRIPT70 "Permission denied" on funciton send(). Is there a way to solve that?